# Why doesn't the softKeyboard open when I tap an editText inside a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

Like the title says, I've got a `viewPager` with some `editText` fields inside. I can select the `editText` fields perfectly fine (emulator and physical device). I see the cursor, and I see the underline color change, indicating it's selected, but I can't type. Tapping on the `editText` fields doesn't open the softKeyboard.

Is this a known issue with a simple fix, or is code needed to identify what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally bumped in to an answer that's working for me, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102074/android-edittext-in-dialog-doesnt-pull-up-soft-keyboard/36264196#36264196).

---

Basically, if you're using the `onCreateDialog()` method, you leave that as is, and add the `onResume()` method below to your `DialogFragment`'s java file.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force softKeyboard with this code:

```java
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Tried it, but softkeyboard doesn't open. But shouldn't I look into fixing what's causing this, instead of working around it?